# Computation of an exterior product

Tags: stokes-theorem, exterior-derivative

In an example of Stokes theorem, I found the following:

> Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth manifold with dim$(\Sigma)=2$ parametrized by $x^\mu(t,\lambda)$, and let $V$ be a 1-form with $V=V_\alpha dx^\alpha$.Then
> $dV=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu V_\nu-\partial_\nu V_\mu)dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\mu V_\nu-\partial_\nu V_\mu)(\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial\lambda}-\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial t})dt\wedge d\lambda$
> where in the last step we took the pullback of the 2-form.

I understand why $dV$ can be written as above, but why is $dx^\mu \wedge dx^\nu=(\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial t} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial\lambda}-\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial \lambda} \frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial t})dt\wedge d\lambda$ ? What does the pullback have to do with any of this?

Comment: If $x^{\mu} = x^{\mu}(t, \lambda)$, then $dx^{\mu} = \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial x^{\mu}}{d\lambda} d\lambda$ and likewise for $dx^{\nu}$. Using these two equations, you can write $dx^{\mu}\wedge dx^{\nu}$ as a function times $dt\wedge d\lambda$.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Thank you, that was easy: I wasn't thinking about the coordinate functions being, well, functions. Do you know how this may be somehow linked to a pullback of something?